# Magento - custom category design

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to have a custom design for my categories like we can see in the picture :
- a banner in one column in the top, and under it (2 columns): the right column and the products in center.

[image]

How can I do that ? And how to remove the category name ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The right way and the long way:** I believe in order to get something to span the top column you are going to have to create a new page template and add it to the layout file.  After you do that, you're going to have create a block that pulls the image into that new div that spans the top.

**The quick and dirty way:** You might be able to do something with CSS and javascript to be able manipulate the image into that position in the layout.

Comment: Thanks Chris, 
I have used this tutorial to create a new Layout : http://thinkclay.com/technology/magento-add-new-cms-page-layout

Now I don't know how can I do to use my new layout for adding a different banner in my categories.

Thanks a lot for more help.